# best way to maintain a socket connection when an app goes to the background

Tags: java, android, android-service

I need to persist a socket connection when my android app goes to background.

Currently, the socket is started, read and written from its own thread. I also store a reference to this thread in a static instance of a class which means i have access to the thread's reference when my app is resumed.

I also don't need this socket to be persisted if the app is destroyed.

Now coming to my question, "Do i need to start a service to maintain this thread or can i just continue with my current design which is to store all such instances that i require when the app resumes in a static container class?"

The only advantage i found so far of using a Service is that the app might be one of the last few to be destroyed during low memory or similar scenarios by the OS (considering the service and the app reside in the same process).

Answer (score 0):

Once your Activity is destroyed, your process becomes a candidate for being shutdown. Most likely, it will linger around a while and not get killed.  But on a lower end device, with less memory, all bets are off.  Go to Developer Options on your device and check "Don't keep activities ...". Exit the activity and see the outcome.

The workaround is to keep a Service active.  Preferably with a notification icon so the user knows it's still running.  That's exactly what I did with my music app to allow the audio stream to keep going even when the user switched apps.

On the flip side, a dedicated socket connection is going to use more battery and more of the user's data plan. If your socket is going to be idle most of the time, a better approach might be have the socket connection connect to the server only when notified via a push notification that there is data available.

Comment: What i require is to keep the connection until the app is destroyed but would like to retain the connection when the app is paused and goes into background. Is there any benefit of using a service vs what i do, keep a reference of the connection in a static container class so i can access it when the app is resumed.

Comment: When you say "app", do you mean "Activity" or "process"?  There's a difference.

Comment: The Activity. When this activity is destroyed, I am releasing all the acquired resources including any threads/socket connections i might have opened. However, when this activity goes to the background, i would still like my socket connection to be able to work from its own thread.

Comment: Got it.  Everything you need to know is [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/processes/process-lifecycle.html). You basically want to be either a "visible process" or a "service process".  Which means either startForeground or startService as appropriate.  Otherwise, you are a "cached process" when the Activity is stopped or destroyed.  At which point, the process can get killed at any time.  Kindly note - even when you Activity is *destroyed* doesn't mean the *process* has necessarily exited - especially if you have a thread.  That's why I call out "process" vs "Activity"